# Is there a way to simplify these javascript functions more?

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas, html5-canvas, simplify

I have lots of small points being created on a canvas, during creation it gets their x, y coordinates and their radius to use later for a collision function I made. This is causing the page to become unresponsive even when I get rid of the interval for it. I think it's just too long of a function to process before going unresponsive. Any help would be much appreciated. Here's the code relating to my question.

```js
var foodX=[]; // array for the x coordinate of the points
var foodY=[]; // array for the y coordinate of the points
var foodR=[]; // array for the radius of the points
var points=[]; //array to store the variable used to create the points for later deletion
function drawFood() { //draws all the points on my canvas
    for (var food=0; food<10000; food++) { //creates 10000 points
        var foodPosX=randInt(0,10000); //create a random x coordinate between 0 and 10000 on the canvas
        var foodPosY=randInt(0,10000); //create a random y coordinate between 0 and 10000 on the canvas
        var r=randInt(3,5) //create a random radius create a random radius between 3 and 5
        ctx.beginPath();
        var point=ctx.arc(foodPosX, foodPosY, r, 0, 2*Math.PI); //this variable draws each point onto the canvas
        ctx.fillStyle= colors[randInt(0,7)]; // uses an array I have with different colors so I can draw different colored points randomly
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
        foodX[food]=foodPosX; //stores my x coordinate in an array for the point currently being created 
        foodY[food]=foodPosY; //stores my y coordinate in an array for the point currently being created
        foodR[food]=r; //stores the radius of the point being created
        points[food]=point; //stores the variable creating the point so it can be deleted when the players collides with it
    }
}
function checkCollision() {
    for (var i=foodX.length-1; i<foodX.length; i--) { //loop through the array backwards to check for collisions
        var fXD=Math.abs(player.pX-foodX[i]); //calculates the distance between the players x coordinate and the points x coordinate
        var fYD=Math.abs(player.pY-foodY[i]); //calculates the distance between the players y coordinate and the points y coordinate
        var rSum=circR+foodR[i]; //adds the radius's together for the player's radius and the foods radius
     if (fXD<=rSum && fYD<=rSum) { //checks if the player is currently touching the point being checked
           foodX.splice(i,1); //deletes the points x coordinate from array
           foodY.splice(i, 1); //deletes the points y coordinate from array
           foodR.splice(i, 1); //deletes the points radius from array
           points.splice(i, 1); //deletes the point the was just collided with
          
            eatFood(); //function for when the player eats the point
        }
    }
}
function randInt(min, max) { //This function creates a random integer between the selected numbers
    min=Math.ceil(min);
    max=Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
}
```

I tried to keep it short and to the point sorry if it's too much or too little. I'm trying to create a game similar to agar.io except it's just going to be an offline, single player version.

Comment: It causes the page to become unresponsive

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if it's functional or not. Would that site be better to post this, for getting the functions more simplified so the page doesn't go unresponsive

Comment: I must have missed the part about the code not working completely.  I removed my comment.

Comment: Have you tried using a smaller loop and running it in parts with an interval to fight against the page unresponsiveness?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When drawing that many points, you need to be clever about how you'll manage them.

Drawing 10000 arcs and filling them 10000 times is consumptive. Instead, try to call the context methods that actually rasterize the minimum possible, e.g by merging all the arcs of a same color in a single sub-path. 
The best in terms of performances, would even be to sort these points by color, but it generally looks quite odd.

For the collision detection, you are currently checking every single point every time. Instead, pack your points in a grid, of *n* per *n* cells. Then in your checkCollision, check only for the points in that cell (well to be good, you'd also check for adjacent ones).
This way, you'll avoid checking all the points in the scene at every checks.

And a bonus from this grid, is that you'll also be able to check if some points are actually hidden by others, and can thus be discarded by the drawing function.

Here is a really rough starting point for you, where the drawing will pack in one subpath consecutive arcs that share the same color, and pack them in a grid which is used by the collision function.

```js
var colors = generateColors(7);
canvas.width = canvas.height = 2000;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var grid = generateGrid(100, 100);
var points = generatePoints(10000);
var dirty = true; // a flag to know when we need to redraw

points.forEach(putInGrid);
// ToDo: mark hidden points
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onmousemove);

anim();

function generateColors(nb) {
  var list = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<nb; i++) {
    list.push(randColor());
  }
  return list;
}
function randColor() {
  return '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF|0).toString(16);
}
  
function generateGrid(width, height) {
  var grid = [];
  for(var i = 0; i<width*height; i++) {
    grid.push([]);
  }
  grid.width = width;
  grid.height = height;
  return grid;
}

function generatePoints(nb) {
  var list = [];
  for(var i=0; i<nb; i++) {
    list.push(new Point());
  }
  return list;
}

function Point() {
  this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
  this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
  this.rad = Math.random() * 10 + 2;
  this.color = colors[Math.random() * colors.length | 0];
}

function putInGrid(point, i) {
  var index = getCellIndex(point.x, point.y);
  grid[index].push(point);
}

function getCellIndex(x, y) {
  if(x > canvas.width - 1) x = canvas.width - 1;
  if(y > canvas.height - 1) y = canvas.height - 1;
  var ratio_x = grid.width/canvas.width;
  var ratio_y = grid.height/canvas.height;
  var norm_y = Math.floor(y * ratio_y);
  var norm_x = Math.floor(x * ratio_x);
  return (norm_y * grid.width) + norm_x;
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
  var point = points[0];
  ctx.fillStyle = point.color;
  ctx.beginPath();
  for(var i=0; i<points.length; i++) {
    point = points[i];
    if(point.color !== ctx.fillStyle) {
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.fillStyle = point.color;
      ctx.beginPath();
    }
    ctx.moveTo(point.x + point.rad, point.y);
    ctx.arc(point.x, point.y, point.rad, 0, Math.PI*2);
  }
  ctx.fill();
}

function checkCollision(x, y) {
  // ToDo: loop through adjacent cells too
  var index = getCellIndex(x, y);
  var cell = grid[index];
  if(cell) {
    cell.forEach(checkPointCollision);
  }
  function checkPointCollision(point, pt_index) {
    if(Math.hypot(x - point.x, y - point.y) <= point.rad) {
      cell.splice(pt_index, 1);
      var newPoint = new Point();
      grid[getCellIndex(newPoint.x, newPoint.y)]
        .push(newPoint);
      points.splice(points.indexOf(point), 1, newPoint);
      dirty = true;
    }
  }
}

function onmousemove(e) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  checkCollision(e.clientX - rect.left,  e.clientY - rect.top);
}


function anim() {
  if(dirty)
    draw();
  modified = false;
  requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4):

I invite you to consider learning more about *Functional Programming* paradigm.
I was a game developer a few years ago, and I found that thinking in FP greatly cleaned up my code and helped me conceptualize game objects better.

Below is a partial solution to your code question, written in FP style; I try to express the main idea that

1. Consider your **food** objects as a collections of properties, and can be expressed as a single JS object.
2. Let **behavior** (ie drawing to screen) be a separate function, working on an individual object
3. Separate **behavior** and **list iteration** (using map function)

Code as follows:

```js
// Assuming the ff:
// 1. an object 'ctx' exists that knows how to draw stuff
// 2. an array 'colors' exists and contains colors you have

const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d')

const colors = ['blue','red','yellow','black','silver','gray','navy','aqua']

// function "newRandomFood" returns a food object whose properties are randomized
function newRandomFood() {
  return {
    x: randInt(0,10000),
    y: randInt(0,10000),
    r: randInt(3,5),
    color: colors[randInt(0,7)] // uses an array I have with different colors so I can draw different colored points randomly
  }
}

// function "drawFood" draws given food object to canvas as a path
function drawFood(food) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(food.x, food.y, food.r, 0, 2*Math.PI); //this variable draws each point onto the canvas. Method doesn't return anything
  ctx.fillStyle = food.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

// function "randInt" creates a random integer between the selected numbers
function randInt(min, max) { 
    min=Math.ceil(min);
    max=Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min))+min;
}

/* generate your foodstuffs */

const foods = Array(1000)     // create an array with 1000 elements
  .fill('')                   // fill each element with anything so iteration won't skip
  .map(_ => newRandomFood())  // fill each element with a random food item

console.log(foods)           // display all the food objects you have

foods.map(food =>             // for every food item...
     drawFood(food))          // ...draw that food
```

Hope this helps.
Cheers,

Comment: That's a good point, but won't improve performance. And `ctx` is `document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');`

Comment: Hi @Kaiido , its helped me optimize development time by being (1) faster to conceptualize since each function has a focused scope, (2) faster debugging due to more granular code, (3) unit test-ability, (4) easier for multiple persons to collaborate since there are less dependencies. FP is a good way of expressing the SOLID principles.

Comment: Yes, I can agree, even though I think all this can hold also with OOP, but that's not relevant to the question. Whatever way this code is written, it will always have the performance issues that Original Poster is facing, and for which the current question has been asked.

Comment: @Kaiido hmmm now that you mention it, I see your point.

Comment: @Brent I think you may be better off using a library that would specifically address canvas drawing like D3 JS (https://d3js.org/)

Comment: This is a good example of if you ask the wrong question you'll get the wrong answer :)  However, if the problem in performance then it would be nice to see sandbox which reproduces the problem because the first step to solve a problem with the performance it is understood the cause